How to convert Axios' response data to `Blob` with typescript
I got this code worked on axios "^0.25.0" but got an error on "^0.28" when constructing a Blob of the response data.
The code:
<--- more codes -->
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
      try {
        const response = await axios({
          url: result?.source_file,
          method: "GET",
          responseType: "blob",
        });
        const blob = new Blob([response.data], { type: "audio/mp3" }); // Doesn't compile. Cannot initialize BlobPart with response.data.
        const buffer = await blob.arrayBuffer();
        const item: ResultFile = {
          audioFileId: audioFile.id,
          type: type,
          buffer: buffer,
          blobType: blob.type,
        };
        db.resultFiles.add(item);
        resolve(blob);
      } catch (error) {
        this.log.error(error);
        reject(error);
      }
    });

Error:
    Type 'AxiosResponse<any, any>' is not assignable to type 'BlobPart'.ts(2322)
const response: AxiosResponse<AxiosResponse<any, any>, any>

I played around with assigning the generic axios<Blob>, but it doesn't seem to work. Any pointers?

Try to resolve the blob in the promise's try-catch and check if the .then(blob) returns the blob you expected.
Here's an example of getting an image with the same responseType option.
const promise: Promise<Blob> = new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
        try {
            const response = await axios.get('https://dummyjson.com/image/150', {
                responseType: 'blob',
            })
            const blob = new Blob([response.data], { type: 'image/jpeg' })
            resolve(blob)
        } catch (error) {
            console.log('error: ', error)
            reject(error)
        }
    })
    
promise.then((blob) => {
    // handle the setter here to take the blob value
    console.log(blob)
})


The problem is the const blob = new Blob([response.data], { type: 'image/jpeg' })
